# Kyocera scanner is visible in “Windows Fax and Scan” but not visible elsewhere in other apps

Tags: windows-10, scanner

I am using a [Kyocera ECOSYS M2040dn](https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/products/product/ecosysm2040dn.html) multi-function device on Windows 10 and in "Windows Fax and Scan" I can scan, but other programs do not see the scanner, or they see it, but the actual scan process hangs.

What happens in NAPS2 is: it detects the TWAIN API, it shows the scanner GUI, it starts scanning (the scanner pulls in the paper sheets), but then hangs, showing a progress bar saying something like "Waiting for TWAIN...")

In Paint, the option "From scanner or camera" is grayed out. NAPS does not find the scanner neither as TWAIN nor WIA. NAPS2 finds only the TWAIN API.

The scanner is shown in "Device Manager", with no issues (no exclamation mark: This device is working properly.).

It worked before on another PC with Windows 7. Now it is connected to a new PC.

Is "Windows Fax and Scan" using a non-TWAIN-based API? Answer: it seems to be using WIA, but somehow differently than Paint and NAPS(2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked (for NAPS2) was:

- install TWAIN driver from Kyocera for this printer
- in NAPS2: select TWAIN driver, in the profile settings click the "Advanced" button and in the new dialog at the bottom select the last value for "Twain Implementation" (something like "old" or similar, I don't have it here now to check)

Note: this problem seems to happen only when the printer is connected via USB cable. When connected over LAN it supposedly works (according to posts on internet, I haven't checked myself)